# How to fix datasets in question to import .csv or geoJSON into Mapbox?

Tags: dataset, mapbox, mapbox-ios

1. I am trying to import a .csv dataset into Mapbox, but I keep receiving the error: "Input failed. Latitude and Longitude fields are not present." The fields however are listed as X and Y in the first two columns of the .csv document. It similarly did not upload when I altered the fields to 'latitude' and 'longitude' respectively. Any assistance here would be appreciated.
2. Lastly when all else failed on the .csv front, I tried to download the geoJSON file but it just automatically opened up in my browser with the text scattered rather than as a file. In fact, the file itself did not even download for some reason. I looked this up and the closes solution here was that I needed Xcode. However, I'm having difficulties downloading Xcode and would be grateful if there is another Mac-based application that can enable the downloading of geoJSON files for upload to Mapbox.

The datasets I'm trying are here: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/yemen-healthsites

Answer (score 0):

This [CSV file errors](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/csv-upload-errors/) troubleshooting guide in our documentation provide full details on the required format of a CSV file to be uploaded to Mapbox Studio.

If you open a GeoJSON file in your browser (such as this one: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/data/stations.geojson), you should be able to right-click on the page and select the "Save page as..." option to save the `.geojson` file to a local directory. You should then be able to open the file in your text editor of choice.